# Can't insert values into MSSQL with PDO

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I'm using PDO to communicate with my database from PHP code and i have the following code:

```
$sql = "SELECT <Column> FROM <tablename>";
```

it works for my mssql database, however when i try to insert some data into it with

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO <tablename> ( <Column> ) VALUES ( '1' )";
```

it fails.

why?

it's funny, but when i run that code from my SQL Server Management Studio - it works.
I can't get it...

The error i get is:

> > SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 515 General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server [515] (severity 16) [(null)]

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Explanation**

This error occurs at run time when an attempt is made to use a null value while inserting or updating a column that does not allow null values.

**Action**

If this error occurs when you are running an UPDATE or INSERT statement, verify that the data inserted or updated matches the column definition for the affected table.

Inserting or updating a column does not allow null values.

Check this: http://www.lcard.ru/~nail/sybase/error/3742.htm or this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258724(v=sql.100).aspx

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.